# When using Multiparty in Node, how do I properly throw an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload, multipart

I'm trying to invoke the error handler function and return a response without crashing the process. The code is simple enough:

```
// Parts are emitted when parsing the form
form.on('part', function(part) {
  // You *must* act on the part by reading it
  // NOTE: if you want to ignore it, just call "part.resume()"

  if (!part.filename) {
    // filename is not defined when this is a field and not a file
    console.log('got field named ' + part.name);
    // ignore field's content
    part.resume();
  }

  if (part.filename) {
    // filename is defined when this is a file
    console.log('got file named ' + part.filename);
    if (part.filename == "CHFILE.TXT"){
      records = CHfilter(part);
    } else if (part.filename == "FCFILE.TXT"){
      records = FCfilter(part);
    } else if (part.filename == "TRFILE.TXT"){
      records = TRfilter(part);
    } else if (part.filename == "TLFILE.TXT"){
      records = TLfilter(part);
    } else {
      throw new Error("File "+part.filename+" is not a recognized file.")
    }

    // ignore file's content here
    part.resume();
  }

  part.on('error', function(err) {
    // decide what to do
    if (err) Log.resError(err, req, res);
    console.log("error function");
    res.send(err);
  });
});
```

But when I upload file with any other name, it throws an error, but the `part.on('error',...` function never runs. So the client never gets a response. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried listening to `error` events on `form` as well? `form.on('error', ...)`

Comment: I haven't, but if that worked, wouldn't that be a bug? I'm throwing the error from the "part", so the part error handler should fire. No?

Comment: Not necessarily, no, it depends on how exactly `multiparty` handles errors internally. It may even be the case that throwing errors inside the event handlers will not cause any `error` event to be emitted.

Answer (score 0):

```js
form.emit('error', new Error("File "+part.filename+" is not a recognized file."));
```